# Problema al llamar una funcion: Problema con variable=True y variable=False

Tags: python

ando haciendo un simple juego RPG por turnos para poder practicar un poco, empecé hace no mucho en python y ando teniendo problemas de vez en cuando.

El problema es que ahora hice una función con def la cual determina si el ataque se hizo o no

```
def fallo():
   chance=random.randint(0,1)
   if chance==0:
     print("El ataque ha fallado")
     ata=False
   else:
     print(f"El ataque ha llegado a {contri.nombre2}")
     ata=True
```

contri.nombre2 es el atributo de nombre del contrincante, realmente no es algo que afecte.
La llamada de la funcion la hago unas cuantas lineas mas tarde de la siguiente manera:

```
eleccion=int(input("Elige una opción >> "))
if eleccion==1:
   print(f"{perso.nombre} empuña su arma contra {contri.nombre2}")
   fallo()

   if ata==True:
      perso.dano=perso.dano*contri.defensa2
      perso.dano=perso.dano/100
```

Y ahí continua con mas cosas sobre la eleccion, el problema que tengo, es que al momento de ejecutar la funcion no toma el ata=True o el ata=False de la funcion, sino que espera a encontrar otro ata fuera de la funcion.
¿Alguna manera de hacer que lea la variable de la funcion y no tener que hacerlo de forma externa?

Comment: Es que las funciones no deberían modificar variables externas... deberían *devolver* variables. En vez de hacer `ata = False` o `ata = True`, pon `return False` o `return True` y cuando llames a la función, en vez de solo `fallo()` pones `ata = fallo()` y ya está. Una función solo tiene acceso a las variables de su `scope`. Es algo demasiado largo para explicar en un comentario, y ya se ha explicado muchas veces eso en SO. Te recomiendo que te acostumbres a trabajar con `return`s, que para eso están!

Comment: Te topaste con un mecanismo de protección, Python por defecto no permite modificar una variable global dentro de una función para evitar modificar accidentalmente una variable que no querías modificar. Te recomiendo leer este link: https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/. Podrías usar global para decirle a Python "quiero modificar esta variable desde aquí", pero generamente es más conveniente hacer lo que dice benito.

Answer (score 0):

Retomando lo que dice la respuesta anterior, puedes hacerlo de dos maneras, con variables globales o sin ellas.

Con variables globales quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
ata = False

def fallo():
    global ata
    chance=random.randint(0,1)
    if chance==0:
        print("El ataque ha fallado")
        ata=False
    else:
        print(f"El ataque ha llegado a {contri.nombre2}")
        ata=True
```

Sin variables globales quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
def fallo():
    chance=random.randint(0,1)

    if chance==0:
        print("El ataque ha fallado")
        return False
    else:
        print(f"El ataque ha llegado a {contri.nombre2}")
        return True
```

Como recomendación extra, si vas a tener un if con una variable booleana, no es necesario compararla:

```
if ata==True: # comparación innecesaria

if ata: # forma óptima
```